# Copying a file from client to server both on same machine in java?

Tags: java, file, weblogic, jdk6

I am copying a large file 300 MB from client to server. I have both the client and server (weblogic) setup locally and still the transfer is too slow. Is there anyway to speed it up only when I have the server on same machine as the client? Here is the code I am using:

```
boolean decodeStream = false;
bytesRead = istream.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
if (bytesRead != -1 && Base64.isArrayByteBase64(buffer))
{
  decodeStream = true;
}
istream.close();

//write the file to the file specified
// if createFile then create a new file
// otherwise append.
OutputStream bos = new FileOutputStream(fileNamePath, !createFile); // second parameter, if true then append...
istream         = file.getInputStream();

if (decodeStream)
{
  // File is encoded, decode it.
  Logger.log("(perform) Decoding file: " + fileNamePath, _moduleName, Logger.DEBUG);

  // Stream came in encoded, so we need to decode it.
  Base64.InputStream stream = new Base64.InputStream(istream);

  while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1)
  {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }

  stream.close();
}
else
{
  // File is not encoded.
  while ((bytesRead = istream.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1)
  {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also see Base64 performance notes: http://java-performance.info/base64-encoding-and-decoding-performance/

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to increase the speed by using buffered io

```
OutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(fileNamePath, !createFile));
istream         = new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream());
```

By default the JVM uses a buffer of 8kB.  I don't know what your BUFFER_SIZE is.